# Getting no response while placing order after following every steps on onecheckot, I have upgrade magento from 1.6.1.0 to 1.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, e-commerce, upgrade

Recently i have upgraded the magento version from 1.6.1.0 to 1.8.0 and all set up is working properly.

While customer trying to checkout they can't place order.

they follow each of the steps and at last step, when they click on the " Place Order ", the order can't be proceed, it do nothing after that.

I have tried to see the problem with console and i got the error something like below.

**JavaScript seems to be disabled in your browser.**
 You must have JavaScript enabled in your browser to utilize the functionality of this website.

Please reply if you have knowledge about this, Thank you in advance for the same.

Comment: If your browser doesn't enabled java script then you cant came across till the place order section(You cant enter even 2nd step). So definitely thats not a problem..Can you please post your site url here ..? But try to check your site in different browsers and systems ..

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply but I found the solution from magento forum and made it correct on live.

Comment: What was the problem..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from below link.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/610464/P30/